# Installing VCBuild.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vcbuild

I have a Visual Studio solution file that uses VCBuild.exe (it's a VS 2008 solution).

I'm trying to figure out how to get VCBuild.exe on the build machine. I've installed the Windows 7.1 and Windos 6.1 SDKs,b ut VCBuild.exe isn't there.

Do I really have to install VS 2008? I installed the SDK suggested in the error message.

```
[c_utils:Rebuild] VCBuild
[11:10:19][VCBuild] C:\BuildAgent\work\8a052fdddf5aac36\Project.sln.cache(392, 5): error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. 
[11:10:19]
```

Comment: It is a Visual Studio build tool, pretty evident from the error message.  Made to build files that only Visual Studio can create.  The SDK only supports make files.

Comment: @HansPassant "pretty evident from the error message". 

Is it? It says one of my options is to install the Microsoft Windows SDK, which I tried and didn't work.